# Jquery Form Data Insert MySQL Database

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, database, servlets

I am trying to write to a MySql Database using an HTML form, with Jquery I can't get the servlet to write to the database. I don't see anything obvious that Im doing wrong.  Here is the code for the servlet and the code for the HTML file.

Servlet:

```
package com.david.servlets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class myForm
 */
public class myForm extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {
              //Get parameters
            String id = request.getParameter("ID");
            String fname = request.getParameter("FirstName");
            String lname = request.getParameter("LastName");


            //Get Connection
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Found a driver");
            Connection dbConnect = null;
            try {
                dbConnect = getConnection("localhost", 7001);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println("Made a connection");


                //Create Query
            String query = "INSERT INTO test.customer (ID, FirstName, LastName) " + 
                    "VALUES (" + id + ", " + fname + ", " + lname + ")";
            PreparedStatement dbStatement = null;
            try {
                dbStatement = dbConnect.prepareStatement(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Execute Query
            try {
                dbStatement.executeUpdate(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //close connection
            try {
                dbStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                dbConnect.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }





public Connection getConnection(String server, int port)
        throws SQLException, NamingException {
    Context ctx = null;
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://"+server+":"+port);
    ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
    DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup ("localmysql");
    Connection conn =  ds.getConnection();
    //conn.setAutoCommit( true );
    return conn;
}    





}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>myForm</title>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        Var ID = $("#ID").val();
        Var FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
        Var LastName = $("#LastName").val();
        $.post("myForm", $("form").serialize(), insertCallback);
    });

    function insertCallback(result) {
        if (result == "success") {
            alert("Record added!");
        } else {
            alert("Could not add Record!");
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="myForm" method="POST">
ID: <input type="number" name="ID">
FirstName: <input type="text" name="FirstName"> <br>
LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName">  <br>
<input type="button" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read about about servlets in particular and HTML in general. Most of your code is much too awkward.

Answer (score 0):

(1)  You need to give your submit button an `id="submit"` for it to work with your click function.

(2) Change `Var` to `var`.

Comment: both of these are fixed, thank you, but this still isn't working as expected.

Comment: Despite JavaScript will be valid after the corrections I doubt that OP's servlet will get called though.

Comment: @user2358627, follow skuntsel's suggestions.  I can demonstrate that the form is getting serialized and the callback is being called (http://jsfiddle.net/9ZVTn/), but I can't help with the other stuff.  BTW, you do not need to waste resources with variable assignments; just serialize the form and post it.

Comment: @DerekHenderson Thanks, I am able to serialize, Im just having an issue with my servlet now.